# referencing JSON with element ID with jquery

Tags: jquery

So this is my first time using JSON with jquery and I have kind of an idea of what I'd like to do and any help, or getting pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

my HTML is set up like so:

```
<div id="agriculture" class="btn"><div>
<div id="treasurer" class="btn"><div>
<div id="war" class="btn"><div>
..... (about 16 of these)


<div id="content_container">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <img id="photo" src="" />
    <div id="summary"></div>
</div>
```

Then I was planning on setting up a bunch of JSON variables like so:

```
var agriculture = {
    "title": "Secretary of Agriculture",
    "location": "url for photo used",
    "summary": "summary of cabinet position"
};
var treasurer = {
    "title": "Secretary of the Treasury",
    "location": "url for photo used",
    "summary": "summary of cabinet position"
};
var war = {
    "title": "Secretary of War",
    "location": "url for photo used",
    "summary": "summary of cabinet position"
};
```

The goal of the set up here was when you click on ".btn" it takes the attr('id') and uses that to call on the correct variable from the JSON because they match and then put that content into the correct divs/img src of content container.

Is this a sound way of doing this? If it is or isn't an someone push me the right direction?

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to store your values within a dictionary structure with named keys instead of creating independent variables. Here is an example:

```
var data = {
    agriculture: {"title" : "Secretary of Agriculture",
                     "location" : "url for photo used",
                     "summary" : "summary of cabinet position"
                 },

    treasurer:   {"title" : "Secretary of the Treasury",
                     "location" : "url for photo used",
                     "summary" : "summary of cabinet position"
                  }
};
```

and then to access your object:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     console.log(data[id]);
});
```

Comment: how would you then go about loading these into divs?  For example, the data-attr Korvin mentioned seemed better then using the ID, I don't know much about that, how would you go about clicking something, and matching the specific clicked object to data that then gets loaded into a container?  Sorry that's a lot of questions, I'm just trying to find a launching point.

Comment: @loriensleafs - see Guffa's answer.  You can combine this idea with his answer.  Just use `data[id]` instead of `window[id]`.

Comment: thanks for the help with this answer Ayman and thanks Brandon for the combining advice!

Answer (score 1):

That's not JSON, that's Javascript object literals. JSON is a text format for representing data.

If you have declared the variables globally, you can access them as members of the `window` object:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var obj = window[id];
  $('#title').text(obj.title);
  $('#photo').attr('src', obj.location);
  $('#summary').text(obj.summary);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nZkfq/

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Sorry buddy! I didn't down vote you, I'm still looking over all of this!

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't describe any reasoning, you search the dom several times on each event firing, and search the window for an arbitrary property (which will not work if this is in a function). These things are all very wrong and may cause conflict in the future. Sorry I didn't reply sooner.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto: I search the DOM several times because there are several elements to fill, exactly as the OP requested. I search the `window` object for a property that is not at all arbitrary, because the id match the variable name, exactly as the OP specified. It works just fine as the variables are global, as I specifically stated in the answer. In what way is that wrong?

Comment: thanks!  This was super helpful and got me to where I needed, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Guffa, you don't need to search the `dom` every time, you can store the jQuery objects in a scoped variable outside of the bind. You are, by definition, searching the window object for arbitrary data. It doesn't matter if @lorienleafs wants it to be global or not, there are no reasons for having it global and several for not having it global. The code you wrote is very substandard, and certainly not following best practices. This site is not for helping the questioner, but for creating a database of answers to common questions. Answering incorrectly is not helpful, it is directly hurtful.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto: That is only your personal opinion on how to write code. Just because my code doesn't fit your opinion doesn't mean that there is anything wrong with it. Just because the answer helps the questioner, it doesn't mean that the answer is incorrect.

Comment: My *personal opinion* is that code should follow standards, and that you should not ***go out of your way*** to write and propagate bad code. I'm not saying that your code is bad because you wrote it, I'm saying that it just is bad code. This isn't a subjective thing, you are advocating dirtying the global scope and running needless large dom searching routines within an event. You should know better than that with 241k reputation. This isn't constructive anymore. If you don't want to write code that is performant, don't. My criticism was meant to be constructive, please take it as such.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto: Yes, it's a subjective thing. There are no objective rules for what's good or bad code. Also, there are no "large dom searching routines" in the event handler in the answer. Using an id to find an element is a very straight forward action that is supported natively by the browser, so there is no searching going on. You are right that this is not constructive, but it never was. You are just trying to present your opinions as if they were some kind of law. They're not.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` is just *JavaScript Object Notation*, by doing `var foo = { bar : "foobar" }`, you are actually creating an [`object literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) and storing it's properties in a variable.

Using the `id` of the element is a bad idea, as the `id` is supposed to be a unique identifier for an element, not a data store. In my example, I used `data-attribute`, but this could be anything you'd like.

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="data-accessor" data-attribute="foo">Click this for foo!</a><br />
<a href="#" class="data-accessor" data-attribute="bar">Click this for bar!</a><br />
```

#### JavaScript

```
var data = {
    foo : "You clicked foo!",
    bar : "You clicked bar!"
}

$('a.data-accessor').click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    alert(data[me.attr('data-attribute')]);
    return false;
});
```

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kgKW/) to see it in action.

And here's an example with multiple data points http://jsfiddle.net/gSgyP/

Comment: I didn't down vote it, but this so far seems to be the best response I've seen, using the data-attr seems better, I dont know much about it.  Two questions what would this look like in a JSON notation and two is it possible to have the variables store more then one piece of information, example: title, description, photo

Comment: @loriensleafs JSON notation doesn't exist. JSON is Javascript Object Notation. All json strings are valid JavaScript objects or arrays. For a JavaScript object to be json though, it must instead be a string, and all keys and string values must be encased in double quotes.

Comment: That's not exactly the case @KevinB, `JSON` supports utf-8 while `JavaScript` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var data = {
    agriculture: {
        title: "Secretary of Agriculture",
        location: "url for photo used",
        summary: "summary of cabinet position"
    },
    treasurer: {
        title: "Secretary of the Treasury",
        location: "url for photo used",
        summary: "summary of cabinet position"
    },
    war: {
        title: "Secretary of War",
        location: "url for photo used",
        summary: "summary of cabinet position"
    }
};

var $title = $('#title');
var $photo = $('#photo');
var $summary = $('#summary');

$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    console.log( data[this.id] );
    $title.html( data[this.id].title );
    $photo.attr('src', data[this.id].location );
    $summary.html( data[this.id].summary );
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/87T3P/